# Integrating spring batch framework to spring MVC framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I want to integrate the spring batch framework to spring MVC framework but getting following error.

Posting code snippet for more clarification.

```
JobParametersBuilder jpBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("inputfilename", "cvs/input/fxe_dadsDevice.dat");
                 jpBuilder.addString("output.file.name", "files/output/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"_test.txt");
                 jobLauncher.run(job, jpBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

XML snippet :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope" />
   <bean id="dadsdeviceItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

          <property name="resource" value=”#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}"/>
          <property name="lineMapper" ref="dadsdeviceLineMapper" />
          <property name="strict" value="false" />
   </bean>
```

Error:

```
FlatFileItemReader:253 - Input resource does not exist URL [file:#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your Question**

1) Please use like this

```
<bean id="inputFile" class="org.springframework.batch.core.resource.StepExecutionResourceProxy">
  <property name="filePattern" value="file://%file.name%"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dadsdeviceItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
<property name="resource" ref="inputFile" />
</bean>
```